# How do you shrink contents to fit a div?

Tags: css, html, printing-web-page, page-break-inside

I am on a project and I have been assigned the task of modifying a report page to make it printable. The report uses PHP to generate tables within divs, but the divs are sometimes greater than 1 page length on print. So, what ends up happening is the tables/divs get broken once the page length runs out. The end result is a cluttered mess.

I have modified the print.css with the tag:

```
.general_report {
    page-break-after: always;
}
```

with all the divs looking like:

```
<div class="general_report">
```

Which cleans up the report a little bit (ie, each section starts with a new page). But this seems to waste quite a bit of paper, and doesn't solve the problem of mid-table page breaking. My other idea was to auto-shrink the contents of the divs to fit 1 page exactly. None of our divs are > 2 pages, so if this was possible I think it would be a good solution... But is this possible? Is there a way for css to adjust font sizes to fit div length?

I googled [scale contents to fit div](http://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=mqG&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&source=hp&q=shrink%20contents%20to%20fit%20div&pbx=1&oq=shrink%20contents%20to%20fit%20div&aq=f&aqi=g-b1&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=805014l806004l0l806999l7l6l0l0l0l1l186l791l2.4l6l0&biw=1440&bih=775&cad=cbv&sei=31l-TtjhA9HWiALurrm5Aw), but everyone seems to be wanting the opposite of what I want (ie, div fits to content, not content fits to div).

Does anyone have any help they can provide? A general example of printing html tables neatly would work, too, as all the results I was able to find involves the non-browser supported CSS (i.e., doesn't work): "page-break-inside: avoid".

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Follwing post explains what you can do to fit text in a DIV with certain width and height: http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/?whichScript=text_fit_in_box

Does that work for you?